# How do I create a new instance of an existing class?

Tags: java, class, instance

I am coding a project in Java, and have created a class with the following code:

```
public class VehInfo {
    private int[][] traffic = new int[20][150]; 
    private int mintime = 0;
    private int numvehicles = 1;
    private int[] vehiclecode = new int[5];

    public VehInfo(int[][] traffic, int mintime, int numvehicles, int[] vehiclecode) {
        this.traffic = traffic;
        this.mintime = mintime;
        this.numvehicles = numvehicles;
        this.vehiclecode = vehiclecode; 
    }
}
```

I want to create a new instance of this class using the following code

```
VehInfo vehinfo = new VehInfo(new int[20][150], new int, new int, new int[5]);
```

However, Netbeans informs me:

> required: (int[][], int, int, int[])
>
> found: (int[][], int[], int[], int[])

What am I missing? I'm clearly not initializing those variables as int[], so why are they being picked up as such?

Comment: What do you think that 'new int' will accomplish?

Comment: new int should be replace by an int

Comment: By which int? What's the value of "new int"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can not initiate simple datatypes like `int`, `boolean`, `char`, `float`, `double` etc.
Change it to something like that:

```
VehInfo vehinfo = new VehInfo(new int[20][150], 0, 0, new int[5]);
```

or remove the passed attributes. It seems to me you set an default to it:

```
private int mintime = 0;
private int numvehicles = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 VehInfo vehinfo = new VehInfo(new int[20][150], 0,0 new int[5]);
```

edit: too late :(

Answer (score 1):

You are struggling with the syntax error,

try this `VehInfo vehinfo = new VehInfo(new int[20][150], 1, 2, new int[5]);`

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
VehInfo vehinfo1 = new VehInfo(new int[20][150], new Integer(1), new Integer(1), new int[5]);
```

or this:

```
VehInfo vehinfo2 = new VehInfo(new int[20][150], 1, 1, new int[5]);
```

Because int (or Integer) are primitives they cannot be instantiated without a value.

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor

```
public VehInfo(int[][] traffic, int mintime, int numvehicles, int[] vehiclecode)
```

requires a situation like this. Suppose you have declared variables:

```
int[][] traffic = new int[20][150];
int mintime = 0;
int numvehicles = 0;
int[] vehiclecode = new int[5];
```

Then you can assign values to them:

```
/** here in your program you assign some values */
mintime = 30;
numvehicles = 2;
vehiclecode[0] = 44;
vehiclecode[1] = 77;
```

And later on create objects of VehInfo class

```
/** then in you program you can create vehinfo objects */
VehInfo vehinfo = new VehInfo(traffic, mintime, numvehicles, vehiclecode);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing your class using a number instead of "new int" like this.

```
VehInfo vehinfo = new VehInfo(new int[20][150], 0, 0, new int[5]);
```

Answer (score 0):

try:
you need to give actual values for the arguments to initialize the object of type VehInfo using your VehInfo contructor you have created:

```
int[][] myint1 = new int[5][5]; //Allocating memory for 5x5 array
myint1 = {{ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5},
          { 6,  7,  8,  9, 10},
          {11, 12, 13, 14, 15},
          {16, 17, 18, 19, 20},
          {21, 22, 23, 24, 25}};

VehInfo myVehInfo = new VehInfo(myint1, 5, 5, int[5]);
```